# XML serialization deserialization not working on Windows server 2012. Error is There Is An Error In Xml Document

Tags: iis-8

I have developed program in VS2010 (.net framework 4.0) in which xml file come from database table and get deserialized using XMLSerializer using C# in asp.net.
Same code is working on production server which is Windows Server 2003, it also works on my local machine which is Windows 7.
Now i am deploying this code on different server Windows Server 2012.

When I host my application on IIS 8.0, it is giving me error `('There Is An Error In Xml Document (1,217)')` for same file which I have tested on my previous server and IIS 6.0 & IIS 7.0.

But on same server (Windows Server 2012) when I test this same code by installing visual studio 2010 , it works fine.
Is there any missing file or missing settings which I should do?

Answer (score 0):

I had pretty much the same problem today. Got XML deserializing errors on Server 2012, but everything worked fine on my local Windows 8 machine.

Suspected it had to do with the patch levels on the server and lo and behold, after a round with Windows Update it deserialized like a god! Have you updated your server lately?